# PHP Session ID is the same but session variables are gone

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I'm having the strangest of problems with session variables that disappear.

First things first, `Firefox` is the only browser on which I see the problem. `IE9` and `Chrome` are working just fine.

Now the context : after being loaded, my page starts performing `Javascript XHR` on my server every minute to refresh a status. Now, after a certain time (I've seen anywhere between `10` to `30` minutes), the request comes in to my `php` file, the session is started (with the same session ID as the previous request (same client of course)), but the session variable are all unset !!

Session timeout is at the default `24` minutes but every request updates a `$_SESSION['time']` variable to keep the session alive.

So in short, the session should not expire and the proper session ID is traveling across, yet after a (rather random) period of time, the session variable are gone.

Any idea on what could cause that ?

Comment: And this doesn't happen with the other browsers? Are they using super cookies perhaps? ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So I've finally fond the cause of that mysterious problem. Everything is clear now.

My web hosting service was offering me to install a bugbase on my domain which I did.

The bugbase was installed in its own directory and was accessed on http://mydomain.com/bugbase

The catch is that the bugbase was PHP based and so is my actual site.

So because they were both on the same domain (mydomain.com), if I accessed both from the same browser, they would both share the same PHP Session. So logging out from one, would also kill the session of the other.

And voilà !!

Once I found that, I could confirm that the problem was seen in any browser where I opened both my site and the bugbase.

I have not tried yet, but the solution to the problem will probably be to install the bugbase on a subdomain.